# Shuffle - within same worker node

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

In spark , there can be multiple worker nodes and each worker node can have multiple executors.

`Shuffle` is movement of data across partitions. Data movement can happen due to one of the below:

- (a) across worker nodes
- (b) within same worker node but across executors (of same worker node)

Do we call both (a) and (b) as shuffle? Given (b) happens within same worker node, would the overhead of data movement less?

Comment: any given partition is operated upon by just one executor. so new parititions are created based on operations like repartition, joins  etc. so that they can be operated by executors.